# Como colocar en itálica algunos labels del eje y?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como colocar en itálica algunas etiquetas del eje y de mi ggplot2? Tales como virus, septoria.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
data.frame(tab) %>%
rename(country = 1,
     let_q5 = 2) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = country, y = let_q5, 
         fill = Freq, label = round(Freq,3))) +
geom_tile() +
geom_text(size = 6, angle = 360) +
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#440154FF", 
                   mid = "white", 
                   high = "#FDE725FF",
                   midpoint = 0) +
labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
    panel.background = element_rect("white"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 25))+
theme(text = element_text(size=26))
```

Estos son los datos de entrada:

> dput(tab)

```
structure(c(83L, 31L, 29L, 27L, 39L, 36L, 40L, 38L, 28L, 0L, 
11L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 14L, 13L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 22L, 14L, 6L, 21L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 5L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 
9L, 3L, 38L, 72L, 25L, 24L, 21L, 27L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 58L, 100L, 64L, 35L, 43L, 
19L, 106L, 48L, 35L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 13L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), dim = c(9L, 18L), dimnames = structure(list(c("GF", 
"LF", "LGF", "LMF", "MF", "MGF", "TF", "TGF", "TMF"), c("Alternaria", 
"Bacteria", "Boremia", "Botrytis", "Cercospora", "Cladosporium", 
"Colletotrichum", "Coniotryrium", "Fumagina", "Fusarium", "Nematodos", 
"Oidium", "Peronospora", "Phoma", "Phytophthora", "Sclerotinia", 
"Septoria", "Virus")), names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

Esta es la imagen de salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la imagen deseada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Muchas gracias!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot` te permite "redefinir" las etiquetas y aplicar ciertos formatos a las mismas:

```
scale_y_discrete(labels=c("Virus" = expression(italic("Virus")), 
                          "Septoria" = expression(italic("Septoria"))))
```

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]